# Is it possible to configure the pop-up delay of Firefox Password Manager?

Tags: firefox

Firefox Password Manager asks me to enter my master password usually around 10 seconds after opening the browser. I would like to be asked immediatly, because the pop up is annoying when you started visiting some website. Is it possible to set the delay time to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *no* delay at all for entering the master password in Firefox. *As soon as you've opened a page* for which you've stored a password, the master password dialog opens. Likely, you've set a default page that takes a long time to load, or as @higuita suggests, you've set your last tabs to reopen, which can take some time. Set a sign-in page having little content as your Homepage, e.g. the minimalist Facebook sign-on page, and don't reopen old tabs, to get a faster password prompt.

Comment: Homepage OR session restore. You are probably like me and have several tabs open and have set firefox to restore the tabs. Session restore is one of the last things loaded and only after the page was loaded and detected the password form, firefox will try to load the password auto-complete and will then ask the password it it exists.

Comment: This works but not ideal.